# Action Script 3 Make phone call

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I have do a program for my family to fast call drag the photo to callit circle or smsit cricle but i need the dial code

^&^&^&^ i want code auto start call not but the number in phone app ^&^&^&^

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

father.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
father.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);

function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent)
{
    e.target.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
}
function onTouchEnd(e:TouchEvent)
{
    e.target.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);

    if (callit.hitTestObject(father))
{
    (??????)
}else if(smsit.hitTestObject(father)){
     gotoAndStop(2);
}}
```

Comment: Posting code that is relevant to your question would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tel: and sms: uri scheme in your mobile phone application:

http://macromedia.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_using_uris.html

To use the tel:URI scheme to launch the system phone dialer

```
public function call():void
{
    const callURL:String="tel:1234567890";
    var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(callURL);
    navigateToURL(targetURL);
}
```

Or, from HTML hyperlinks in a TextField:

```
var call:TextField = new TextField();
call.htmlText ="<a href='tel:1234567890'>Call</a>";
```

SMS text messaging would be:

```
public function sms():void
{
    const callURL:String="sms:1234567890";
    var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(callURL);
    navigateToURL(targetURL);
}
```